# C++ iStream, If-Else & Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, istream

I have this iStream function to read in a .txt file of data in the format of:

```
  Pink Floyd: Dark Side of the Moon
  0:01:30 - Speak to Me
```

My function almost works perfectly.

Here are my problems that I just can't figure out.
1) It prints (outputs) as each track is added to an Album (so prints `x` copies of the first album, each with the next track attached.
2) When a new Album is created, it keeps the old tracks from the previous album and continues to add them one-by-one. (so the final album has every single track from all albums)

Obviously I want each album to only be printed once, and each album to only have its own songs... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would perhaps be better to ask this question at the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) sister site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code.

> `stringstream stringstreamFirst(line);`

You aren't using the variable `stringstreamFirst` and `line` is empty at this point.

> `Album anAlbum(artistName,albumTitle,trackVector);`

There are a number of problems with this line.

- It's using the wrong values.
  One the very first line, `artistName`, `albumTitle`, and `TrackVector` are empty. When you finally come across a new album, the `artistName`, `albumTitle`, and `TrackVector` are those for the previous album, not the current one. The values are correct by the time you get to the tracks on an album -- but that's not when you want to create a new album object.
- It's in the wrong place.
  As placed, this statement creates an `Album` object for each line in the input file. The right place to create a new album object is when you have encountered a new album entry in the input file.

> `stringstream stringstreamNew(line);`
>   `stringstream stringstreamNewNew(line);`

Why the convoluted names, and why do you need two variables? An alternative would be to use but one `stringstream`, created as the first line of your `while` loop.

> if (!(line[8] == '-'))
>   else if (line[8] == '-')

Don't replicate your boolean conditions like this. If you mean `else` (which is what you mean), just use `else`. The line is either an album entry or a track entry; there is nothing else.

> else // These lines are missing

You don't have any error handling. What if you can't parse what presumably should be an album entry, or what presumably should be a track entry?

What you need to do (pseudocode):

```
while (getline(istr, line)) {
   stringstream linestream (line);
   if (line looks like an album line) {
      if (not the first line in the file) {
          // Create an album using the artist name, album title, and track vector
          // and add this album onto the vector of albums
      }
      // Parse the line for artist name and album title, preferably handling errors
      // Clear the trackVector that now pertains to the previous album
   }
   else {
      // Parse the line for track duration and name, preferably handling errors
      // Add the track to the track vector.
   }
}
// Create an album to cover the last album plus set of tracks
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `Album` perhaps store references (or even pointers) to its constructor arguments?

Don't do that, it means there's only ever just one vector of tracks - the one called `trackVector` - shared between albums, which keeps getting added to.

You should either have an `addTrack` member in `Album` *or* not construct an `Album` until you've read all the tracks depending on whether it makes sense for an `Album` to be mutable.

Also, you never modify `aC` - and what do you expect `artistName = artistName` to accomplish?